# Multiple XA data sources in a single JTA transaction

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, jta, java-ee-5, xa

I have been programming with the Java EE platform for a while, but sometimes I am missing the bigger picture.

Using a EJBs and [Container-Managed Transactions](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bncij.html), how can I perform operations on multiple data sources in a single transaction?

My code looks like this:

**aaa-ejb module**

Contains a `persistence.xml` pointing to the first data source.

```
@Stateless
public class AaaDao {
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    // using defaults: @TransactionAttribute(REQUIRED)
    public void foo(...) {
        em.persist(...);
    }
}
```

**bbb-ejb module**

Contains another `persistence.xml` (a different persistence unit) pointing to the second data source.

```
@Stateless
public class BbbDao {
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    // using defaults: @TransactionAttribute(REQUIRED)
    public void bar(...) {
        em.persist(...);
    }
}
```

**ccc-ejb module**

Depends on the above two modules.

```
@Stateless
public class CccBean {
    @EJB AaaDao aaaDao;
    @EJB BbbDao bbbDao;

    // using defaults: @TransactionAttribute(REQUIRED)
    public void qux(...) {
        aaaDao.foo(...);
        bbbDao.bar(...);
    }
}
```

I mean: is it really that easy? I am always a little skeptical when things seems to work "magically", I always suspect there is a "catch".

Using Java EE 5, EJB 3.0, JPA 1.0 on Oracle WebLogic 10.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is really that easy. `CccBean.qux` starts a new XA transaction, the callers to `AaaDao`/`BbbDao` reuse the same transaction (because of `REQUIRED` as you point out).  The `EntityManager` use `DataSource`'s and the `DataSource` will `enlistResource` an `XAResource` with the Transaction. When C`ccBean.qux` exits, the transaction will be committed, and the transaction manager will drive 2-phase commit on both `XAResource` registered by the DataSource's.